# Reducing connections to a vertex

Tags: meshlab

I designed a belt buckle type device using Tinkercad, which uses geometric figures that you can section and put together.  I'd like to add some modeled curves and ridges, so I've tried to import it as a OBJ file into Sculptris, but I get a "mesh error" message that says: "Too many connections to a vertex (max 24)". I've done some poking around and now understand that Tinkercad produces a mesh that uses lots of triangles, and when many of these converge on one point, they cause problems for Sculptris.

I read that with Meshlab I can edit the mesh somehow to fix the area defined by the excessive number of triangles converging on a single vertex. I've imported the OBJ into meshlab, and viewed the wireframe. There are a couple of spots with a large number of these edges converging on a couple of points. Most of these clusters of triangular faces seem to be on a couple of planes, so many could be merged to create fewer faces without losing any information. I've been struggling to figure out to do this.

I've selected the faces that I'd like to merge (and I've tried selecting all faces connected to one vertex) and then applied each of the simplification options, and several other things under the Filters tab. Deleting the faces just leaves a hole in the model.  I can't seem to figure out how to reduce the number of triangles converging on those few specific points. Anyone have any advice that's likely to be digestible by a beginner just trying to figure this stuff out? Some of what I've read about this has been well beyond my comprehension level.

Answer (score 0):

> Deleting the faces just leaves a hole in the model.

You can close the hole using `Filter -> Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction -> Close Holes`

There might be some other way to do what you are trying to achieve, but from what I can think of, this is the simplest one.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.